# Linq to SQL join then order by

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, join

I have the following two classes:

book_page

- chapter_title
- order within chapter
- (other fields)

chapter

- chapter_title
- order

I have a collection of book_pages with their chapter titles. I want to be able to get the book_page collection sorted by the order that their "chapter_title" comes up in the "chapters" collection and then sort by the "order within chapter" field.

I tried writing a join on the chapter_title column then ordering by chapter.order, then by page.order_within_page, but no luck. Any suggestions?

My Code:

```
var ordered_pages= from chapter in chapters
                        join page in book_pages
                        on chapter.chapter_title equals page.chapter_title
                        select new{order = chapter.order,page = page}

var finalList = from row in ordered_pages.OrderBy(c => c.order).ThenBy(p =>p.page.order_within_chapter)
                select row.page;
```

This doesn't really work and is ugly even if it did. Am I missing some way of using LINQ to do this?

Comment: It would help if you posted the broken code because, at least in concept, what you have already done should work.

Comment: @brandon post your LINQ query and let us know how it's not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var a = db.Chapters;
var b = db.Pages
.Select(p => new { page = p, chapter = a.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Title == p.Caption) })
.OrderBy(p=>p.chapter.order).ThenBy(p=>p.page.order).Select(p=>p.page).ToList();
```

Or

```
var b=db.Pages.Join(a, p => p.Caption, p => p.Title, 
(p, q) => new { page = p, chapter = q }).OrderBy(p => p.page.Code)
.ThenBy(p => p.chapter.t1).Select(p=>p.page).ToList();
```

Comment: pages don't have a chapter property, is there a way to assign this relationship in the linq query? I wouldn't need the join if they already had a chapter property. Only the "chapter_title" which I get in plain text

Comment: awesome. Much cleaner. I need to learn this version of LINQ. It's much more natural to use in c#. Thanks alot

Answer (score 10):

I beleive this is what it should look like.

```
var ordered_pages =
        from chapter in chapters
        join page in book_pages
            on chapter.chapter_title equals page.chapter_title
        orderby page.order_within_chapter
        orderby chapter.order
        select page;
```

the page.order_within_chapter will order first, then the chapter.order will run.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
   var ordered_pages = 
       from chapter in chapters
        join page in book_pages on chapter.chapter_title equals page.chapter_title
        order by page.order_within_chapter, chapter.order
       select page;
```